# React Js. Как передать данные от одного компонента к другомy?

Tags: reactjs

Прошу не судить меня строго. React начал изучать недавно. Есть знания по JS, которые хочу научиться применять . Большая часть кода взята с урока. Я пытаюсь дописать компоненту поиска, чтобы при вводе в строку поиска оставались только нужные мне заметки. Но уже 3 день подряд не получается - не могу передать данные из компонента Search в компонент NotesApp в notes. Пытаюсь это сделать при помощи props - задаю в `<input transfer={this.state.searchValue} >` Выдаёт ошибку ( Unknown prop `transfer` on  tag ). Также пытался передать в `<Search />`, но тоже безрезультатно. Подскажите в чём ошибка или хотя путь в каком двигаться ? Заранее , благодарен. Полный  код вот здесь https://github.com/VadoSevich/React-MyPractice-/blob/master/React%234/note.js

```
    var Search = React.createClass({

      getInitialState: function(){
        return {
          searchValue: ''
        };
      },


      handleSearch: function(event) {
          var searchQuery = event.target.value.toLowerCase();
          var searchNotes = this.props.notes.filter(function(el) {
              var searchValue = el.text.toLowerCase();
              return searchValue.indexOf(searchQuery) !== -1;
          });

          this.setState({
              searchValue: searchNotes
          });
      },

      render: function() {

         return (
            <input type="text" className="search" onChange={this.handleSearch} transfer={this.state.searchValue}/>
        );

      }

    });

var NotesApp = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function(){
      return {
        notes: []
      }  
  },

  componentDidMount: function(){
    var localNotes = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('notes'));
    if (localNotes) {
        this.setState({ notes: localNotes});
    }
  },

  componentDidUpdate: function(){
      this._updateLocalStorage();

  },

  handleNodeDelete: function(note){
    var noteId = note.id;
    var newNotes = this.state.notes.filter(function(note){
        return note.id !== noteId;
    });
    this.setState({ notes: newNotes });
  },

  handleNodeAdd: function(newNote){
      var newNotes = this.state.notes.slice();
      newNotes.unshift(newNote);
      this.setState({notes: newNotes});
  },

  _updateLocalStorage: function() {
    var notes = JSON.stringify(this.state.notes);
    localStorage.setItem('notes', notes)
  },

  render: function(){
      return (
        <div className="notes-app">
          <h2 className="app-header">NotesApp</h2>
          <Search notes={this.state.notes} />
          <NoteEditor onNoteAdd={this.handleNodeAdd}  />
          <NotesGrid notes={this.state.notes} onNoteDelete={this.handleNodeDelete}/>
        </div>  
      );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
    <NotesApp />,
    document.getElementById("mount-point")
);
```

Answer (score 9):

Идеология React подразумевает передачу данных сверху вниз, то есть из родительского компонента в дочерний. Вы же хотите передать данные снизу вверх, чтобы это сделать, можно из родительского компонента передать функцию, которая может изменять состояние родителя и вызвать эту функцию в ребенке, передав необходимые данные при вызове.

```js
var Search = React.createClass({

  getInitialState: function(){
    return {
      searchValue: ''
    };
  },


  handleSearch: function(event) {
    var searchQuery = event.target.value.toLowerCase();
    // Передаем введенные данные в родительский компонент.
    this.props.onHandleSearch(searchQuery);
    this.setState({
      searchValue: event.target.value
    });
  },

  render: function() {

    return (
      <input type="text" className="search" onChange={this.handleSearch} value={this.state.searchValue}/>
    );

  }

});

var NotesApp = React.createClass({

  getInitialState: function(){
    return {
      notes: [],
      searchValue: '',
    }
  },

  // Передаем этот метод в компонент Search.
  // Именно так можно передать данные из дочернего компонента в родительский.
  handleSearch: function(value){
    this.setState({searchValue:value});
  },

  render: function(){
    // данные фильтруем здесь
    var filteredNotes;
    if(this.state.searchValue !== ''){
      filteredNotes = this.state.notes.filter( note => note.text.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.searchValue.toLowerCase()) !== -1 );
    } else {
      filteredNotes = this.state.notes;
    }

    return (
      <div className="notes-app">
        <h2 className="app-header">NotesApp</h2>
        <Search onHandleSearch={this.handleSearch} />
        <NoteEditor onNoteAdd={this.handleNodeAdd}  />
        <NotesGrid notes={filteredNotes} onNoteDelete={this.handleNodeDelete}/>
      </div>
    );
  }

});
```

Обратите внимание, что в родителя передаются не измененные данные, а лишь значение формы и уже в родителе данные фильтруются.
Рекомендую почитать про ["глупые" и "умные"](https://maxfarseer.gitbooks.io/redux-course-ru/content/konteineri_i_komponenti.html) компоненты.

Comment: Не помешало бы добавить текста к коду.

Comment: Большое спасибо, думал, что не достаёт знаний по JS. Решил перечитать учебник. Но видно дело, что не знал где искать по React нужную инфу, думаю со временем всё прийдёт. Ещё раз спасибо )

Answer (score 1):

Лучше всего сразу начать использовать Redux, хоть поначалу он кажется сложным и запутанным, но на самом деле это проще чем передавать пропсы в компоненты особенно если эти компоненты между собой не связаны

Answer (score 0):

По двум ссылкам ниже описаны методы передачи данных между компонентами.
Соответственно для разных случаев используются конкретных тип передачи данных.

[8 не-Flux стратегий взаимодействия компонентов React](http://andrewhfarmer.com/component-communication/)

[Передача данных между компонентами React](https://medium.com/@ruthmpardee/passing-data-between-react-components-103ad82ebd17)

И есть еще вариант взаимодействия через Flux библиотеку.